# Why can't chrono::time_point be added some duration in a function

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I'm working with `std::chrono` of C++11 and I just found something weird. Here is my demo:

```
// time point type
template <typename T = std::chrono::milliseconds>
using Clock       = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, T>;
using TimePointMs = Clock<>;

// get current time point
// param timeZone can be negative
template <typename T = std::chrono::milliseconds>
inline Clock<T> getCurrentTimePoint(int8_t timeZone) {
    return std::chrono::time_point_cast<T>(std::chrono::system_clock::now()) +
        std::chrono::hours {timezone};
}


int main() {
    std::cout << "now0:" << std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now()).time_since_epoch().count() << std::endl;
    auto now1 = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now())
        + std::chrono::hours {1};
    auto now2 = getCurrentTimePoint<std::chrono::seconds>(0);
    auto now3 = getCurrentTimePoint<std::chrono::seconds>(1);
    auto now4 = getCurrentTimePoint<std::chrono::seconds>(5);
    std::cout << "now1:" << now1.time_since_epoch().count() << std::endl
              << "now2:" << now2.time_since_epoch().count() << std::endl
              << "now3:" << now3.time_since_epoch().count() << std::endl
              << "now4:" << now4.time_since_epoch().count() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As you see, I wrote a very simple function, which returns a time_point added with some `std::chrono::hours`.

But the output is so weird.

```
now0:1641446050  // OK
now1:1641449650  // OK
now2:1641446050  // ???
now3:1641446050  // ???
now4:1641446050  // ???
```

So `now0` and `now2` should be the UTC, `now1` should be the UTC + 1h. But `now3` and `now4` equal to `now0`? I did pass a `3` and a `5` as the parameters of the function `getCurrentTimePoint` but it looks like they just disappeared?

Comment: You've got typo `timezone` vs `timeZone`, compiler found unused parameter

Comment: Now I have no idea why, but you have a typo that seems to fix it: `timezone` -> `timeZone`. https://godbolt.org/z/Efad8YPfh

Comment: The `timezone` variable that is mistakenly used in your code comes from https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tzset.3.html. It seems to be included through `#include<chrono>`. It is of type `long`, so the conversion to a duration worked without error.

Comment: Lesson for today: *Always* build with extra warnings enabled. Using GCC or CLang, add `-Wall -Wextra` (at least); For MSVC add `/W4`.